# Error when connecting android device with C# web service

Tags: java, c#, android, soap, ksoap2

I am trying to connect my android device with simple C# web service but I am getting this error

> org.xmlpull.v1.XmlpullparserException:expected:START_TAG{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/} Envelope(position:START_TAG@2:7 in java.io.inputStreamReader@1db98270)

It is my code:

```
package com.example.khalifa_.webservice;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/findContact";

    private static final String OPERATION_NAME = "findContact";// your webservice web method name

    private static final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";

    private static final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://192.168.1.3:29824/Service.asmx";
// for the SOAP_ADDRESS, run your web service & see
//your web service Url :1506/WebSite3/Service.asmx ,1052 will be change according to your PC

    TextView tvData1;
    EditText edata;
    Button button;
    String studentNo;
//http://localhost:1827/WebSite1/Service.asmx/HelloWorld

    //http://10.0.2.2:1827/WebSite1/Service.asmx
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        tvData1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,     OPERATION_NAME);
                PropertyInfo propertyInfo = new PropertyInfo();
                propertyInfo.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                propertyInfo.name = "eid";

                edata =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                studentNo=edata.getText().toString();

                request.addProperty(propertyInfo, studentNo);

                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                        SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.dotNet = true;

                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

                HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);

                try  {
                    httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                    Object response = envelope.getResponse();
                    tvData1.setText(response.toString());
                }  catch (Exception exception)   {
                    tvData1.setText(exception.toString()+"  Or enter number     is not Available!");
                }

                tvData1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            }
        });

        //client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        //new Read().execute("text");
    }
}
```

Comment: Describe what else did you try, please. Is this your first attempt?

Comment: need my web service code ?

Comment: Sorry, that won't help me. I don't know anything about android, I've been reviewing posts and asked you for more information for people who know the answer to have easier job with figuring it out. Web code service may be useful, but it would be even better to know what research you did, what did you read, tried changing in code, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You must write code in background thread. use asynctask for background thread. For more info [refer this](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-call-asp-net-web-service-in-android/).

Comment: Would be great if leave a reference link as well so that your answer is more helpful.

Comment: check following link                                             http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-call-asp-net-web-service-in-android/